# Find whether a SATA port is available from within Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sata, optical-drive, pata

A relative has a faulty DVD drive connected by a PATA connector to the motherboard of his computer. Since most new DVD drives are SATA, I wonder how can I tell if I would be able to connect a new SATA DVD drive to the motherboard.

I would have to explain it over the phone, with the help of pictures, so I am looking for simple instructions/ways to verify it. The person that will do it is able to open the computer's case and remove, say, the video card to remove the dust on it. He just needs help to find a free SATA connector on the motherboard.

Comment: Your description is confusing.  How was a SATA device connected to a PATA interface?  This information is normally display within the BIOS.  I don't understand how knowing this information will help though.

Comment: Well, actually I was sent a picture of a DVD drive connected by PATA. Now, since nowadays most drives are connected by SATA, I just wondered if there was a way for me to know (without being physically there) if there is a SATA connector left on the motherboard so I could make them buy a SATA drive in plug it.

Comment: This said, I realize it was not that clear... ;)

Comment: I will edit the question